# Java - Deleting database value through jList and jButton

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm new to jList and jButton and in need of a small assistance using the aforementioned elements.

So I'm trying to delete a single value from a database by the help of jList and jButton, but I am in the dark here because I don't know how to handle the sql statement.

I've taken this code from the internet for list selection listener

```
class SharedListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();

        int firstIndex = e.getFirstIndex();
        int lastIndex = e.getLastIndex();
        boolean isAdjusting = e.getValueIsAdjusting();
        output.append("Event for indexes "
                      + firstIndex + " - " + lastIndex
                      + "; isAdjusting is " + isAdjusting
                      + "; selected indexes:");

        if (lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            output.append(" <none>");
        } else {
            // Find out which indexes are selected.
            int minIndex = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
            int maxIndex = lsm.getMaxSelectionIndex();
            for (int i = minIndex; i <= maxIndex; i++) {
                if (lsm.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                    output.append(" " + i);
                }
            }
        }
        output.append(newline);
    }
}
```

Used it like this in the main

```
listBuku.addListSelectionListener(new SharedListSelectionHandler(){
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
        //I don't know what to put in here
        }
```

And my jButton for delete is still empty..

How to obtain the value clicked by the user in the list so that the program will delete the corresponding value in database??

Update here's the whole code

```
JTextArea output;
    JList list; 
    JTable table;
    String newline = "\n";
    ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel;
    DefaultListModel listModelIsiBuku = new DefaultListModel();
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public Main() {
        initComponents();
        listBuku.setModel(listModelIsiBuku);

        koneksi();

        isiBuku();

        listBuku.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); 

        String[] listValues = new String[]{"Value1", "Value2"};
        //JButton button = new JButton("Delete");
        JList<String> listBuku = new JList<>(listValues);    
        //Only allow one item to be selected at once
        listBuku.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); 
        try (PreparedStatement deleteValue = connection.prepareStatement("Delete from foo where columnToDelete = ?"))  {
        deleteButton.addActionListener((e)-> {
        String valueToDelete = listBuku.getSelectedValue();
            try {
                deleteValue.setString(1, valueToDelete);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                int deleteCount = deleteValue.executeUpdate();
                //In the variable deletecount you can find the amount of columns which have been deleted in the database
                //Maybe you want to check it.
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            });
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        listBuku.addListSelectionListener(new SharedListSelectionHandler(){
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){

        }

    });

    }
```

For the connection code

```
private void koneksi()
    {
        //load jdbc driver for mysql database
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to load Driver");
    }

    //Establish connection using DriverManager 
    try {
     connection = 
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to connect to database");
    }

    //if connection is successfully established, create statement
        if(connection != null) {
        try {
           statement = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
           System.out.println("Unable to create statement");
        }
    }

}
```

And the rest of the functions which I would use for input, checking the values from database, and make list selection listener

```
public void inputBuku(String input)
    {
        String sqlInputBuku = "insert into BOOK (BOOK_TITLE) values ('" + input + "')";

        try {
            statement.executeUpdate(sqlInputBuku);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tidak dapat input buku : " +ex);
        }

    }

    public void isiBuku()
    {
        try
        {
        String sqlIsiBuku = "select * from BOOK";
        ResultSet rsIsiBuku;
        rsIsiBuku = statement.executeQuery(sqlIsiBuku);

        while(rsIsiBuku.next())
        {
            listModelIsiBuku.addElement(rsIsiBuku.getString("BOOK_TITLE"));
        }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tidak dapat mengambil isi buku : " +e);
        }
    }

    class SharedListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();

        int firstIndex = e.getFirstIndex();
        int lastIndex = e.getLastIndex();
        boolean isAdjusting = e.getValueIsAdjusting();
        output.append("Event for indexes "
                      + firstIndex + " - " + lastIndex
                      + "; isAdjusting is " + isAdjusting
                      + "; selected indexes:");

        if (lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            output.append(" <none>");
        } else {
            // Find out which indexes are selected.
            int minIndex = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
            int maxIndex = lsm.getMaxSelectionIndex();
            for (int i = minIndex; i <= maxIndex; i++) {
                if (lsm.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                    output.append(" " + i);
                }
            }
        }
        output.append(newline);
    }
}
```

These are the auto generated codes which I have no idea of what to do to them

```
private void inputBukuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void inputButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void deleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String sqlDeleteBuku = "select * from BOOK";

        try {
            statement.executeQuery(sqlDeleteBuku);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tidak dapat menghapus buku : " +ex);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are mainly looking for is:

```
JList#getSelectedValue();
```

For let me give you this small example:
This works in case you show in your List directly the value which is stored in the database and which shall be deleted. It required Java 8.

```
//Given:
Connection con = //TODO get database connection    


String[] listValues = new String[]{"Value1", "Value2"};
JButton button = new JButton("Delete");
JList<String> list = new JList<>(listValues);    
//Only allow one item to be selected at once
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); 
try (PreparedStatement deleteValue = con.prepareStatement("Delete from foo where columnToDelete = ?"))  {
    button.addActionListener((e)-> {
        String valueToDelete = list.getSelectedValue();
        deleteValue.setString(1, valueToDelete);
        int deleteCount = deleteValue.executeUpdate();
        //In the variable deletecount you can find the amount of columns which have been deleted in the database
        //Maybe you want to check it.
    }
}
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the `try (` statement.. It says it needs another `)`.. Where should I try putting it? And should I put the whole code inside the main class?

Comment: And how to bind the command to the `JButton` itself? Should that `JButton` be changed to `deleteButton` which is the name of the button in design tab?

Comment: in your example no JButton is given. So i just created one here to show you how it works. feel free to change it to the one you used. The missing bracket is added in the post.

Comment: I am quite confused of where to place the code.. I got it working but I don't know whether to put it inside the `jButton` which is `deleteBuku` or should it be in the main? And I got an error saying `No operations allowed after statement closed`

Comment: I've added the whole code.. I wish I don't have to but I am really unable to comprehend the syntax and how to use the code..